# how to i get this value as a variable

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I got this java that sends a user input to php to be verified and put whatever the php echoes into the div "password_feedback" I did have a separate piece of java that tried to see if the "password_feedback" was equal to "Good". but that didn't seem to work(even though it worked with username) so now I'm trying take the Password_feedback result and directly make it a variable to compare. so could anyone help me figure this out, I would appreciate it.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#password_feedback').load( 'password-check.php').show();
 
 $('#password_input').change(function(){
  //username: is name of variable sent to php, form is name of form, username is name of input
  $.post('password-check.php', { password: form.password.value}, 
  function(result) {
   $('#password_feedback').html(result).show();
  });
 
 });
  if ('#password_feedback' == "Good"){
  document.getElementById("check2").innerHTML = "good";
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.

1. You are comparing `"Good"` to the **string** `'#password_feedback'` instead of the value you get back from the Ajax request
2. You are doing your comparison *when the DOM is ready* instead of *when the response for the request comes back*

Change `'#password_feedback' == "Good"` to `result == "Good"` and move the entire `if` statement inside the function you pass to `$.post`.